# Colored App bar comes out completely white Vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I am trying to load up a Vuetify app bar using this code:

```
<template>
  <v-toolbar dark color="primary">
    <v-toolbar-side-icon></v-toolbar-side-icon>
    <v-toolbar-title class="white--text">Title</v-toolbar-title>
    <v-spacer></v-spacer>
    <v-btn icon>
      <v-icon>search</v-icon>
    </v-btn>
    <v-btn icon>
      <v-icon>apps</v-icon>
    </v-btn>
    <v-btn icon>
      <v-icon>refresh</v-icon>
    </v-btn>
    <v-btn icon>
      <v-icon>more_vert</v-icon>
    </v-btn>
  </v-toolbar>
</template>
```

Using this code, I just get a blank app bar that is white. When I highlight the Title text, I can see it, so it's like the color is being set to white as well...

I have this in my main.js file:

```
// The Vue build version to load with the `import` command
// (runtime-only or standalone) has been set in webpack.base.conf with an alias.
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import router from './router'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css'
import 'material-design-icons-iconfont/dist/material-design-icons.css' // Ensure you are using css-loader
Vue.config.productionTip = false

Vue.use(Vuetify, {
  theme: {
    primary: '#3f51b5',
    secondary: '#b0bec5',
    accent: '#8c9eff',
    error: '#b71c1c'
  }
})

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  components: { App },
  template: '<App/>'
})
```

When I remove the `dark color="primary"` declaration, I get an app bar that appears correctly, just without color (obviously).

Why are my colors not being added properly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to wrap in `v-app` to make `dark` props works properly.

```
<v-app>
 <v-toolbar dark color="primary">
    <v-toolbar-side-icon></v-toolbar-side-icon>
    <v-toolbar-title>Title</v-toolbar-title>
    <v-spacer></v-spacer>
    <v-btn icon>
      <v-icon>search</v-icon>
    </v-btn>
    <v-btn icon>
      <v-icon>apps</v-icon>
    </v-btn>
    <v-btn icon>
      <v-icon>refresh</v-icon>
    </v-btn>
    <v-btn icon>
      <v-icon>more_vert</v-icon>
    </v-btn>
  </v-toolbar>
 </v-app>
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ittus/oskwkzwn/1/)

[Vuetify Doc about Light and Dark](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/style/theme)